# Finding the largest modulus of congruence for two integers?

Tags: math, computer-science, modulo, number-theory

Given two integers is there an easy way to find the largest modulus of congruence for them? i.e. a % n == b %n, Or even to enumerate all of them?  Obviously, I could try every value less than them, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

I tried doing something with gcds, but then you just get things where a % n == b % n == 0, which isn't as cool as I was hoping for, and I'm pretty sure this isn't necessarily the largest n.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a and b are the numbers, then we consider:

```
a = nx + r
b = ny + r
```

Where n is the modulus we want to find, and r is the common remainder. So,

```
a - b = n(x - y)
```

Maximum n is achieved with x - y = 1. So,

```
n = a - b
```

(If I understood the question correctly.)

Comment: Yes, that's just what I was looking for.  It makes sense that the difference between the two is a valid modulus, it wasn't obvious to me that this was the maximum.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool :) Just make sure to check for the degenerate case where a = b, in which case n would calculate to 0, which is meaningless. The 'real' n in that case would of course be 'a' (or 'b').

Comment: Good catch, Brian. I should have stated that as an assumption. :)